# Is it possible to have a state-either hybrid monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad, either

### Goal

I'm trying to write the internals of an interpreter, and, for ergonomics purposes, I think I want to have a monad that works like both the state and either monads.

For example, I'd like to do some things with either style:

```hs
checkedAddress :: Integer -> Interpreter Int
checkedAddress n = if (n < toInteger (minBound :: Int))
                      then fail $ "Address " ++ show n ++ " is too low"
                   else if (n > toInteger (maxBound :: Int))
                      then fail $ "Address " ++ show n ++ " is too high"
                   else return $ fromInteger n
```

I'd like to do other things with state style:

```hs
setInstructionPointer :: Int -> Interpreter ()
setInstructionPointer ip (Machine _ mem) = ((), Machine ip mem)

getInstructionPointer :: Interpreter Int
getInstructionPointer m@(Machine ip mem) = (ip, m)
```

### Questions

Is it possible to create a state-either hybrid monad like this?

If it's impossible, why is it impossible? Is there an alternative that has the nice ergonomics and, I assume, efficiency of early termination of (like either stops further processing through `Left m >>= _ = Left m`) this approach?

If it's possible, how do I write the monad instance for the type? I tried, but I got stuck when writing `(>>=)` because I can't see a way to know what constructor to produce without knowing the runtime `Machine` value.

```hs
data Interpreter a = Running      (Machine -> (a, Machine))
                   | Halted       (Machine -> Machine)
                   | Error String (Machine -> Machine)

instance Monad Interpreter where
  return = Running . (,)
  Running f     >>= g = DontKnowWhich $ \ m -> let (a, m') = f m
                                               in  case g a of
                                                        Running h ->
                                                        Halted  h ->
                                                        Error s h ->
  h@(Halted  _) >>= _ = h
  e@(Error _ _) >>= _ = e
```

Comment: What you need is a monad transformer. Look into StateT and EitherT from the [mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combined monad should look like this:

```
newtype Interpreter a
  = Interpreter { runInterpreter :: Machine -> (Machine, Either String a) }
```

It takes a state, the `Machine`, returns a modified state, and returns either success or failure.

```
deriving instance Functor Interpreter
instance Monad Interpreter where
    return x = _exercise
    Interpreter x >>= f = _exercise
instance Applicative Interpreter where pure = return; (<*>) = ap
liftEither :: Either String a -> Interpreter a
liftState :: State Machine a -> Interpreter a
```

In general, to put monads together, you put one "inside" the other:

```
Interpreter a <~> State Machine (Either String a)
```

You could do it another way, `s -> Either String (s, a)`, but then you don't get the state back on error. (Note that `Either String (State Machine a)` does not work: whether or not you fail would not be allowed to depend on the state. It's only an `Applicative`.)

You do not have to write the `Monad Interpreter` instance yourself. The [`transformers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2) package (shipped with GHC) provides "monad transformers" for constructing monads compositionally. A monad transformer is a `T :: (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)` that takes a monad as argument and returns a new monad.

```
type Interpreter = ExceptT String (State Machine)
liftEither = except
liftState = lift
```

`ExceptT String` is a monad transformer, and `State Machine` is a monad, so `Interpreter = ExceptT String (State Machine)` is also a monad. The other way I mentioned before would be `StateT Machine (Either String)`.

The next step is to use the [`mtl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2). This library provides classes on top of the `transformer` types such that monad-specific actions like `throwError` and `get` are overloaded to automatically lift themselves through as many monad transformers as needed. With the `mtl`, you can leave your own functions polymorphic in the monad stack:

```
checkedAddress :: MonadExcept String m => Integer -> m Int
checkedAddress n = do
  -- you don't need to branch, failure short-circuits!
  when (n < toInteger (minBound :: Int)) $ throwError _
  when (n > toInteger (maxBound :: Int)) $ throwError _
  pure (fromInteger n)

setInstructionPointer :: MonadState Machine m => Int -> m ()
setInstructionPointer ip = modify \(Machine _ mem) -> (Machine ip mem)

getInstructionPointer :: MonadState Machine m => m Int
getInstructionPointer = gets \(Machine i _) -> i

-- combined:
checkedOffsetJump :: (MonadState Machine m, MonadExcept String m) => Integer -> m ()
checkedOffsetJump off = setInstructionPointer =<< checkedAddress =<< (off +) <$> toInteger <$> getInstructionPointer
-- read: setInstructionPointer(checkedAddress(off + toInteger(getInstructionPointer())))
```

And you can nail them down later, usually at the very end:

```
runState $ runExceptT $ checkedOffsetJump 0x8000 :: Machine -> (Either String (), Machine)
```

Comment: Stacking them the other way is reasonable too; which is better depends on context.

Comment: @dfeuer I did say that, but OP's attempt seems to imply they want to recover the `Machine` on failure.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Thanks! The `State Machine (Either String a)` type gave me the clue I needed to make the hybrid monad's `(>>=)` from scratch and the talk about monad transformers is a nice preview of them.